# spinoff entity value / adjusted close of a spinoff

Tags: options, equities, valuation, corporate-actions

When company $A$ spins off company $B$ (i.e. $A = A'+B$), how do we know exactly the adjustment factor of $A'$  and $B$ before trading

Note I am not asking to **value** the new companies. That's a whole different topic. I am just asking for the “adjustment price" of a corporate action. For example if $A$ closes at $\\\$100.0$, it pays $\\\$5.0$ dividend, then the adjusted close of $A$ is $\\\$95.0$. The adjustment factor on bloomberg terminal would be 0.95. Before market open, suppose nothing happens, we know the "fair value" of $A$ is about $\\\$95$ since it loses $\\\$5.0$ of value due to dividend.

But when yesterday [AIV spinned off AIRC](https://seekingalpha.com/news/3644345-aimcos-spinoff-of-apartment-income-reit-closes),  how exactly do we know how much value is in AIV and how much is in AIRC? Turned out AIV is valued at around $\\\$5.47$ so it spinned off almost 90% of its value.

Supposedly the price for AIRC is tracked by "AIRC WI" but that ticker had no trading on NYSE the day before as far as I know. It was also incredibly hard to look up the prices of "AIRC WI" the day after when the spinoff really happened (i had to dig through raw market data). Is there a better data source?